# What is Win32 x86-64 CONTEXT::VectorRegister for?

Tags: winapi, x86-64, simd

In the Win32 x86-64 [CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-context) structure, there are members named `VectorRegister` and `VectorControl`.  What are those for?

The XMM registers are stored in `Xmm0` through `Xmm15`.  Extended vector registers such as the YMM and ZMM registers are stored in "XSTATE" extended context structures, not in the `VectorRegister` array.  Also, there being 26 vectors in that array is really weird.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wonder if it isn't coincidence that there are 26 non-volatile (callee preserved) vector registers in the vectorcall calling convention and 6 are volatile (caller preserved) for a total of 32. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017#register-usage